# Logstash Config file at an endpoint

Tags: logstash

Is there a way to have the logstash config file be served from a HTTP endpoint?
I want to be able to share the configs from say a S3 bucket endpoint...
And just want to have them in one place.

I thought I saw somewhere I could...but cannot find it in the docs-

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is little* unsecure to change your configs from web end-point...

But just for sake of curiosity you can do it.

You cant use `nginx + php-fpm` and from php you can call `bash` script which will perform all what you want!)
Also you must set appropriate file modes.
Maybe this approach little bit sophisticated - but it possible to achieve your aim.

PS: Anyway it is bad practice. Better use something like CodeDeploy or Jenkins etc.